# How do i clear UserPrincipal cache

Tags: java, active-directory, acl

The following Code returns the UserPricipal for a given Groupname. But after deleting a Group this Code still returns me a UserPrincipal (the deleted one). Is there a way to delete this "cache"?

```
UserPrincipalLookupService upls=fs.getUserPrincipalLookupService();
UserPrincipal who;
try {
    who = upls.lookupPrincipalByName("myDeletedGroupName");
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
return;
}
```

Because when setting Windows ACL's i need the UserPrincipalName. And after recreating a deleted Group with the same name the ACL is set to the old group not to the new - and when looking in the Windows-GUI i see the old objectSid in the ACL list instead of the new Group(-name).

Steps in short:

```
    1. creating AD Group "xxxx"
    2. setting ACL in File f for xxxx
    3. deleting Group "xxxx"
    4. deleting ACL
    5. create new Group "xxxx" in AD 
    6. setting ACL in File f for xxxx
    -> the OldSid from the deleted Group is the ACL Principal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Active Directory is a distributed system.  There may be multiple domain controllers serving the same domain.  So, after you delete an object from Active Directory via one domain controller, you may still be able to find the deleted object on another domain controller before the replication kicks in.

Even you have only one domain controller, you still need to pay attention to which service that you are consuming.  There are normal LDAP service and Global Catalog service.  Global Catalog service is a **cache** of objects from different domains, including your local domain, in the same forest.  Its purpose is to allow user to do a global search across all the domains in the same Active Directory forest.  You will find similar problem on Global Catalog.  After you delete the object on domain controller, you are still able to find the deleted object from the Global Catalog until replication kicks in.  The good news is within the same domain controller, this replication usually happens quickly.

I am not familar with `UserPrincipalLookupService` in Java but very likely, it's using Global Catalog to find the User Principal.  You may want to check whether the class allow you to specify which domain controller to use and which global catalog to use when performing the query.  If the class doesn't allow you to specify the server, I am afraid you have to wait for the replication.

Comment: There is no way to specify a Server in UserPrincipalLookupService. I think the **%logonserver%** environment variable shows the current connected Domain-Controller. But i want to set many ACL's remote, so the Remote and my Computer have probebly not the same DC.

Comment: +1 helpful; same problem here, I searched MSDN up and down for this already. when you say "replication usually happens quickly"... does anybody know a source for times-to-live or where this caching/replication strategy can be configured on a Windows 2012 PDC?